# Using Bootstrap during mid development

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that Bootstrap is an JavaScript framework that can be used as basis for creating web sites or web applications and that it consists of utility classes that an be used. However, consider the following scenario:

I am already in mid production of my web application and was unaware of the benefits (and existence) of Bootstrap. I, therefore, have several CSS files which already exist. After realizing and reading into the benefits of Bootstrap (such as it's Grid system as my web application should be accessible via mobile device), I have decided I wish to implement the Bootstrap CSS files into my application. Will the introduction of the Bootstrap CSS files:

1. Nullify my other linked CSS file to a HTML file? I understand it is based on the order of the `<link href="">` but if both CSS files have styles for a class called `btn` - does that mean I have to edit my own created CSS file?
2. Will I have to edit large portions of my HTML code? For example, I have seen that one of the many elements `bootstrap.min.css` targets is `input[type=search]`. My own created CSS file also targets `input[type=search]`, but since `<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">` is above my own created css file link, it will use the styling of the element `input[type=search]` in `bootstrap.min.css`.
3. Will implementing Bootstrap also be a lengthy, resource hungry process to implement in mid production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, imho, I wouldn't call Bootstrap a JavaScript framework, in most cases, you won't even need the js parts of bootstrap and just use less/css.

I think you need to study some css (for an hour or so), but to answer your questions;

1. If you happen to use the same class names in your own css and load it (link) after bootstrap, it means you are overwriting the css rule from bootstrap, which is totally fine.
2. Confused here, as I said in (1), if your rules are after bootstrap's, yours are taken into account. You may need to edit large portion of your html to add bootstrap classes. In some cases they need nested classes in place, especially for forms etc.
3. Depends how deep in mid production you are and how big your project is. I would start modifying a few pages first and see how tedious it is and decide afterwards.

While you are at it, you should also check other alternatives to bootstrap if you haven't already. Bootstrap is good and mature, but there are other serious contenders around too.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted some existing sites to Bootstrap. It took me a while, but it was mostly straightforward, and the results were worth the effort.

You could try a very easy test to see what happens to your pages when you link the bootstrap.css file. Try inserting the link before then after your own css link. If that goes well, you can experiment with some HTML markup edits.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use `bootstrap` and link it before your CSS, your HTML code will  apply bootstrap CSS rule first, then override by your CSS.
2. As first question, which you need to custom style, just override by your CSS.
3. It's depend on your requirement. If your product **MUST** display well on mobile, you should apply `bootstrap`, it will save your development time very much. But its also risky because you need to edit your HTML code.

P/s: If your project use many features of `jQueryUI` , you shouldn't apply `bootstrap` at this time. Many conflicts between `bootstrap` & `jQueryUI`.

Also, you can find some template code of bootstrap at: http://bootsnipp.com/